# Insert subview behind TabBar from child view of TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, subview

I have `TabBar` with 2 tabs. At some point, from either of the 2 tabs, I want to add a view that is visible on both tab views but behind the `TabBar`.

So I thought, insert a subview into the `TabBarController` but below the `TabBar`.

This works fine in principle and I have the view behind the `TabBar` but now covering my 2 tabs as I wanted. However, it doesn't actually load. Just its background loads and only `viewDidLoad()` is called, **not** `viewWillAppear()` or any others.

I have also tried calling `addChildViewController(myVC)` on the `TabBarController` which has no effect, and also manually calling `viewWillAppear()` on the view controller I add which also has no effect (and I'm also dubious about whether manually calling `viewWillAppear()` is permitted or not?).

Is what I'm trying to do possible? What am I missing? Or should I be attempting this some other way?

Comment: Don't manually call viewWillAppear. 

I don't get what you mean, are you adding views or trying to add View Controllers?

Comment: Add a subview to the tab bar controller, so it covers any tabs views, but add it behind the tab bar itself. I've actually solved it now by using a view controller in place of the tab bar controller and programatically setting up the tab bar and tab bar controller how I want then. I will add a full solution shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, when inserting a subview into a `UITabBarController` behind it's `UITabBar`, although the view is visible to the user, the system itself seems to think it is not and so although `viewDidLoad()` is called, `viewDidAppear()` and subsequent methods are not.

However, adding a subview above the `UITabBar` seems to work fine. So I solved this by adding my own new `UITabBar` as a subview to the `UITabBarController` (set up basically exactly as the default one would be) and then removing the `UITabBarController's` default `UITabBar`.

Then when later inserting my view into the `UITabBarController`, I insert it as I was doing originally but instead below/behind my custom `UITabBar` and it seems to load fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to remove and recreate the tabBar. What you need to do is after you insert your custom view, you can then bring the tabBar to the front again.

```
//bring the tabBar to the front after inserting new view
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.tabBar)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good way:

Add the function below and call it in `viewDidLoad` of your initial VC. It unwraps your tab bar controller instance (which is optional), and then inserts the view you always want visible just below the tab bar.

```
private func setupAlwaysVisibleView() {
    guard let tabBarController = self.tabBarController else { return }

    tabBarController.view.insertSubview(alwaysVisibleView, belowSubview: tabBarController.tabBar)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using optionals for tabBarController or removing current tabBar. Simple add your view below tabBar view. Swift 5, XCode 11.

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    @IBOutlet var instructionsView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        self.view.insertSubview(instructionsView, belowSubview: self.tabBar)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this inside the init() method for your UITabViewController:

```
 view.insertSubview(alwaysVisibleView, belowSubview: self.tabBar)
```

no need to dispatch to another method if you are using a subclass of UITabViewController.